# Merge two Pandas datadrames and specify rules for merging cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes that I want to merge, but I want to specify a rule (function) for how it decides to merge cells that are shared.

The two rules I am interested in are

1. If one cell is NaN and the other has a value, use the one with a value
2. If two cells have different (non-NaN) values, raise an error

For example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([["R", np.nan], ["R", "S"]], index=[0, 1], columns=["a", "b"])
df1

    a   b
0   R   NaN
1   R   S
```

#### Rule 1 - If one cell is NaN and the other has a value, use the one with a value

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["R", "S"], ["R", "S"]], index=[0, 2], columns=["a", "b"])
df2
    a   b
0   R   S
2   R   S
```

Now, when I go to merge them

```
df1.merge(df2, how="outer")
    a   b
0   R   NaN
1   R   S
2   R   S
```

I would like it to replace the empty (NaN) cells with the non-NaN value. i.e.

```
    a   b
0   R   S
1   R   S
2   R   S
```

#### Rule 2 - If two cells have different (non-NaN) values, raise an error

In addition, I would like to add an "integrity validation" function that checks if two cells with the same index and column name, that are non-NaN, have the same value.

For example

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([["R", "R"], ["R", "S"]], index=[1, 2], columns=["a", "b"])
df3
    a   b
1   R   R
2   R   S
```

If I were to try and merge this with `df1`, I would get the following

```
df1.merge(df3, how="outer")
    a   b
0   R   NaN
1   R   S
2   R   R
```

But I want this to error as the cell `[1,"b"]` is `S` in `df1`, but `R` in `df3`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with uses [`combine`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html).

First, create a function that handles the logic of comparing two cells

```
def comp(c1, c2):
    if pd.isna(c1):
        return c2
    elif pd.isna(c2):
        return c1
    elif c1 != c2:
        raise ValueError(f"{c1} != {c2}")
    else:
        return c1
```

The function that `combine` calls take two Series, so we just create a `lambda` that applys `comp` to each Series element-wise

#### Rule 1

```
f = lambda s1, s2: np.array([comb(c1, c2) for c1, c2 in zip(s1,s2)])
df1.combine(df2, f, overwrite=False)
    a   b
0   R   S
1   R   S
2   R   S
```

#### Rule 2

```
df1.combine(df3, f, overwrite=False)
...clipped error message...
ValueError: S != R
```